# MATCH / Exact SEARCH to retrieve Headers from Table Definition

Tags: excel, search, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a sample table definition A1:C4 assigned as "Foods" as follows. I am searching keywords on another sheet and retrieving the Header name of the table, if they exist in the table body. For unique data as in F6 the following formula works well, where as if two columns have partially same keywords "Orange" as in A3 and B4, the formula does not return the desired result.

```
=INDEX(Foods[#Headers];1;MAX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F7;Foods))*COLUMN(Foods))))
```

So to have an exact match I tried the following formulae, but neither worked exactly. They are returning the entire Header list as in H7:J7.

```
=INDEX(Foods[#Headers];1;MAX((ISNUMBER(MATCH(F7;Foods;0))*COLUMN(Foods))))
=INDEX(Foods[#Headers];1;MAX((ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRUE;EXACT(F6;Foods);0))*COLUMN(Foods))))
```

[image: Table Definition]

How should I get the exact header for the matched data in the table? I definitely have to search for the exact keyword, as there are several partially matching keywords in other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may benefit from SUMPRODUCT, COLUMN and INDEX:

[image]

My formula to get header is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$1;1;SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$C$4=F6)*COLUMN($A$2:$C$4)));"not found")
```

Comment: I have modified your formula to adapt to the table definition and it is working fine when the data is found. If the entered data does not exist in the table then it is SPILLing with all the headers. Is it possible to avoid the SPILL issue without an additional IF?

Comment: I have no spill issues because I got Excel 2007, so I'm afraid i cannot get a solution for that part.